# Dishwasher needed?

Tags: appliances, dishwasher, new-home, texas

Is it mandatory to have a dishwasher installed in your texas home? We just bought a house, and of course we’re remodeling. The inspector won’t pass us unless we have all appliances. We don’t want a dishwasher though. I can’t find anything on whether or not this is mandatory to have.

Comment: Are you located in a city? If so, which one. Some cities have additional requirements.

Comment: The only appliances that should be required for inspection are the ones connected to water and/or gas.  Any that are just plugged in should only need their receptacles inspected.  Your own house just need what you use.  Most appliances are nice to have, not necessary a need to have, depending where you live.  Don't use a dishwasher should not need to have one.

Comment: I can imagine it be required in a commercial kitchen in some jurisdiction, but not in a residential kitchen. Is there an open dishwasher port on your disposer maybe? Is there a cable for hardwiring the dishwasher poking out of the wall? Is installing a dishwasher explicitly listed on the permit? I guess an inspector could not believe your stated intention, but he would be out of bounds if he rejected your scope based entirely on his suspicions.

Comment: You might try an in-person visit to the building department counter to ask about this. If they claim that you need a dishwasher, ask gently and firmly for the written reference. Escalate in writing to management as needed. (I’d agree that just installing a broken unit that you found on the curb would be a ‘solution’, but it introduces cabinetry problems.)

Comment: Is there an empty spot with plumbing and wiring for a dishwasher?  If so, he may say it's not finished until the dishwasher is installed.

Comment: Note that unless you plan to die in that house, the next owner may want a D/W, and your (or your heirs') sale price may be dinged if you don't have one.  Like not having a washer/dryer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd work hard to get the kitchen I want (ie, no dishwasher), but if the permits office insists, I'd approach it like this:

Order a 24" wide base cabinet. Plan your kitchen such that the cabinet is adjacent to the sink. Run the flooring a foot or more into this space (full depth is better). Set all the cabinets, except don't attach the 24" one permanently. (Use clamps or sex bolts to maintain alignment.) Once the rest of the cabinets are anchored, pull out the 24" one and hide it somewhere. Install a temporary dishwasher. Don't forget plumbing and electrical connections, because an inspector swinging their administrative muscle might look. Once you've finalled, pull the crappy dishwasher, cap the electrical and plumbing and shove your 24" base cab into place.

(The side benefit of all this is that you'll have a 24" space with plumbing and electrical that can easily receive a dishwasher, should you choose to sell the place. Odds are good that your preference for a dishwasher isn't shared by the house buying public.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the reason is open drains, pipes and wires.  Try covering/capping everything up and then try again.  Inspectors can just get fussy.  Ours refused to pass our kitchen because there was hole in the bench, as the tap was still a few months away.  We had a butlers pantry with a sink and taps.  But he insisted that the tap had to be installed in the kitchen bench.

In our part of the world, the inspector's work gets audited, so they try to cover their backs.

If that doesn't work, but an old non-working one just to get a pass.